# What is the best/easiest way to expose a RIA Services collection as a pageable list of ViewModels in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, ria, wcf-ria-services

In Silverlight 4 (or higher), I want to have a view model that exposes a pageable list of view models that are derived from a pageable list of entities that are lazily retrieved from RIA services.

For example here could be a code behind/view model:

```
    // Entities: Thousands exist, so they will be loaded lazily using the DataGrid's paging features.
    private EntitySet<ExampleEntity> Entities { get; set; }

    // View models: This list is a view of the Entities list.
    public IList<ExampleEntityViewModel> EntityViewModels {
        get {
            return CreateDerivedCollection(this.Entities, this.CreateViewModel);
        }
    }

    // This method will be called whenever Entities has a new item added.
    public ExampleEntityViewModel CreateViewModel(ExampleEntity entity) {
        return new ExampleEntityViewModel(entity);
    }
```

and here could be some Silverlight 4 XAML:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntityViewModels}" />
    <sdk:DataForm ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntityViewModels}" />
```

If I weren't concerned about paging, I'd use library called [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/) to create the property.  Obtics is nice because the list that Obtics creates is "Reactive", meaning when the underlying entity list changes, the view model list will automatically reflect the changes by monitory property change and collection change events based on an expression I use to create the view model list.

However, I don't believe (and I could be wrong) that this Obtics list will work right with the Silverlight DataGrid/DataForm/etc. controls because it doesn't act like a pageable collection.

So my question is: what is the best way to accomplish this?

I've looked at a bunch of view model libraries (Prism, SimpleMVVM, Caliburn.Micro, and RIAServices.ViewModel), and none of them seem to support this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class DomainCollectionView of RIA Services Toolkit.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/12/02/introducing-an-mvvm-friendly-domaindatasource-the-domaincollectionview.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't expose a collection of View Models.  Though the DomainCollectionView code is based off of code from a blog, so it could be copied and modified to fit my needs.  Which is actually what I ended up doing.